# Regex to parse line from Multicraft

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to parse lines coming from a server console (Multicraft) following this format:

```
"source" <[ignore]"username"> "message"
```

Here's an example of chat:

```
[Server] <Johndonne> hello everyone!
[Chat] <[VIP][Owner]bit2shift> hey
[Chat] <[Mod]waisman> hello there
[Chat] <[Builder]bluesniper> hey john xD
```

My first strategy was with this regex:

```
^(?P<source>\[[^\]]+\])?\s*<\[.+\](?P<sender>[^>]*)>\s*(?P<message>.*)$
```

but it fails if there's no [tag] before the username, such as when the text string is:

```
[Server] <Johndonne> hello everyone!
```

To test the regex I used re.findall(regex, line) to get a tuple with the params.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make that part optional by putting a zero-or-one quantifier (`?`) around it, like this:

```
^(?P<source>\[[^\]]+\])?\s*<(?:\[[^\]]+\])?(?P<sender>[^>]*)>\s*(?P<message>.*)$
```

But this pattern would capture `[Owner]bit2shift` in the `<sender>` group when the input string is `[Chat] <[VIP][Owner]bit2shift> hey`. You might want to group multiple tags, using a zero-or-more quantifier (`*`):

```
^(?P<source>\[[^\]]+\])?\s*<(?:\[[^\]]+\])*(?P<sender>[^>]*)>\s*(?P<message>.*)$
```

This would capture just `bit2shift` in the `<sender>` group.

Comment: It worked on a simple python script. Lets see if Multicraft handles it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make it optional:

```
In [23]: x = """[Server] <Johndonne> hello everyone!
[Chat] <[VIP][Owner]bit2shift> hey
[Chat] <[Mod]waisman> hello there
[Chat] <[Builder]bluesniper> hey john xD"""

In [24]: rx = re.compile('^(?P<source>\[[^\]]+\])?\s*<(?:\[.+\])?(?P<sender>[^>]*)>\s*(?P<message>.*)$')

In [25]: [rx.search(xi) for xi in x.split('\n')]
Out[25]:
[<_sre.SRE_Match at 0x6c3ba48>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x6c3b7e8>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x6c3bae0>,
 <_sre.SRE_Match at 0x6c3bb78>]

In [26]: [rx.search(xi).group() for xi in x.split('\n')]
Out[26]:
['[Server] <Johndonne> hello everyone!',
 '[Chat] <[VIP][Owner]bit2shift> hey',
 '[Chat] <[Mod]waisman> hello there',
 '[Chat] <[Builder]bluesniper> hey john xD']
```